# How to write the Hamiltonian for the free fermion on the plane?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, fermions

On a cylinder, the Hamiltonian and mode expansion for the (periodic) free fermion are
$$H=\sum_{n\ge \frac12} \omega n\,\, c_n^\dagger c_n, \quad \psi(x)=\sum_{n\ge\frac12}i\left(c_n e^{-iknx}-c_n^\dagger e^{iknx}\right) \ .$$
Since $e^{iHt}c_ne^{-iHt}=c_ne^{-i\omega t}$ and $e^{iHt}c_n^\dagger e^{-iHt}=c_n^\dagger e^{i\omega t}$ the Heisenberg representation of $\psi(x)$ reads
$$\psi(x,t)=\sum_{n\ge\frac12}i\left(c_n z^{-n}-c_n^\dagger z^n\right)\ ,$$
where $z=e^{ikx+i\omega t}$. So far so good. Now let's map the model to the plane. The standard procedure is to use the conformal property of $\psi(z)$ to write $\psi_{plane}(w)=\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)^{\frac12}\psi_{cylinder}(z)$, where $w=e^{z}$ maps cylinder to the plane. The result is
$$\psi_{plane}(x,t)=\sum_{n\ge\frac12}i\left(c_n w^{-n-1/2}-c_n^\dagger w^{n-1/2}\right)\qquad (1)$$

My problem is that I do not see how this Heisenberg representation can be obtained from $\psi(x,t=0)$. Indeed, $w(z,t=0)=e^{ikx}$ and hence
$$\psi_{plane}(x)=\sum_{n\ge\frac12}i\left(c_n e^{-ik(n+\frac12)x}-c_n^\dagger e^{-ik(n-\frac12)x}\right)$$

However, if we assume the same Hamiltonian for the plane as for the cylinder, turning on the Heisenberg evolution does not yield (1), instead
$$\psi_{plane}(x,t)=\sum_{n\ge\frac12}i\left(c_n w^{-n}e^{-ikx/2}-c_n^\dagger w^{n}e^{-ikx/2}\right) \ .$$

What am I doing wrong here? How to write the Hamiltonian on the plane so that the Heisenberg time-dependence is in agreement with (1)?